# How to see what IIS config elements are changed from default?

Tags: windows, iis, powershell, deployment, msdeploy

On Windows Server 2012, 2012-R2 and 2016 (e.g. IIS v8.0 and up)

We have an IIS setup, that has evolved over the years.

How do I extract its "delta to default IIS" so we can make a script to set up other machines the same way?

I know how to do this on Apache and Tomcat (do a diff of the running config file against the default config).

How do I do it against IIS, and really capture everything?

The goal is NOT to "share" or "export" configs. The goal is to KNOW what about this IIS instance diverges from a stock IIS, so we can script it.

Answer (score 0):

The xml config file for IIS is at:

```
%SystemRoot%\System32\inetsrv\config\applicationHost.config
```

just do a diff with a version from a fresh server.

Each site may have settings in their own web.config file, but you don't need to script those if you just copy the whole site.

> and really capture everything?

Many other changes on a server can affect how IIS works, registry changes (very few) for example. File permissions and users are another thing to keep in mind.

`applicationHost.config` is a good starting point.

Comment: OP enhanced to clarify.

Answer (score 0):

IIS supports Shared Configuration check out the link below it will guide you through exporting the existing settings and then importing them to other IIS server plus setting up a file share where all IIS servers will get their config in the future.

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/manage/managing-your-configuration-settings/shared-configuration_264

Comment: Thanks!  I have done the "export config" from IIS via IIS Admin and via the deploy / migration tool. But that doesn't help me know what has been done to a server.

Comment: OP enhanced to clarify